# Logging directly to Logstash using Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm currently using an ELK stack to manage my application logs. It was running fine until the day we needed to manage logs on ALL microservices. Using spring, I was logging in application.yml, logstash would read it and pass it to the rest. However now, I can't have an application.log for every microservice, nor have logstash read every of theses. I've heard of appenders, which I tried using without much luck. Is there a way I could log to the logstash-* file directly, without application.log ?
For example, I'd use a `logger.log("test");` which would write it to the logstash-* file. This way I could write to the same file with every microservices.

Comment: I ran into a similar situation and I found that using the ElasticSearch REST API instead of Logstash became much easier

Comment: I'll check that out

Comment: Heres a reference to the rest client I used from them: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the relevant part of your `application.yml`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant application.log, edited the question. There's no relevant part, it's just logs. However, @gkgkgkgk 's solution seems to be a good one. I'll look into that but it seems to work.